# Ubuntu 22.04 locks up when /usr/local is symbolically linked to an automount location

Tags: 22.04

Ubuntu 22.04 locks up when /usr/local is symbolically linked to
an automount location. I did:

```
cd /usr
mv local local.old
ln -s /some/automount/location local
cd local
```

Then, the whole system freezes.

Does anyone know why? Has /usr/local become a special location on
the system. It works fine with 20.04 and earlier versions of Ubuntu,
CentOS, and RedHat.

Comment: It might help to know why you are doing this and what you expect to accomplish.

Comment: It's a shared /usr/local that has matlab and various applications share on a group of machines.

Comment: How and when does it lock up? While starting? After being logged in? After a while? After you do something?

Comment: After the symbolic link is added, the machine freezes after a 'cd /usr/local' or 'df' or just wait a while to have it freeze. Once the machine locks up, no one is able to ssh to the machine and the monitor freezes.